# what does "out of range" mean?

Tags: mysql, database

I have checked these statements with mysql  and no error will happen and also the out put will be 0 rows BUT my friend checked it and he found an error for SELECT becaouse it is out of range !! IS he correct? thanks

```
CREATE TABLE T1(A INTEGER NULL);
SELECT * FROM T1;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your friend to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with those two lines.

"Out of range" normally means that some value is outside the expected range of valid values. For example if you have an array of length 2, trying to access position number 10 in that array could lead to an "array index out of range" error (depending on your programming language).

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see anything wrong with it - but I haven't got an install of mysql handy at the moment to test with.